# Does using the inline translate configuration option make Magento slower?

Tags: performance, magento, translate

I could not find any resources on this topic. Some downloaded translation files are not 100% correct. There are 2 ways to fix these translations, with the backend option which enables frontend inline translation. Or programmatically with a csv file. Is the first one slower? If yes is this significant?

I have a site which performs quite slow. Now i am trying to optimize it and i was thinking this might be an issue. Are there any good resourses, maybee with benchmarks?